# How to predefine XSD file name with jaxb2-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I use a code below to generate an XSD from annotated java-classes. Default name of the XSD is always "schema1.xsd". How should I pre-define it using only that plugin? At the moment I use maven-antrun-plugin for file renaming. [Plugin manual](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/schemagen-mojo.html) doesn't contain relevant information.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>schemagen</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <sources>
          <source>src/main/java/***some package***</source>
        </sources>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/schemas</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer has been found. It is not enough to only annotate your java-classes with the JAXB annotations. In the DTO package should exist file "package-info.java" with the following content:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://your-namespace")
package com.your.package;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

And the plugin declaration should look like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>schemagen</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <sources>
      <source>src/main/java/com/your/package</source>
    </sources>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/schemas</outputDirectory>
    <transformSchemas>
      <transformSchema>
        <uri>http://your-namespace</uri>
        <toFile>your-namespace.xsd</toFile>
      </transformSchema>
    </transformSchemas>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: not working with packe-info.java